# ReSharper: how do i bring back a specific vs2010 key shortcut?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper

vs2010 comes with a wonderful ctrl+, shortcut. it was hijacked by ReSharper. I'd like to bring it back w/out having to bring back all vs2010 settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tools->Options->Environment->Keyboard

Change Edit.NavigateTo to Ctrl+,

Change whatever "Shortcut currently used by" to another key.